# Blank Properties Window of Active X Button Control Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an issue with my active x control and when I unprotected the sheets and workbook and right clicked to check properties, I see this. Please help.

[image: As you can see, the properties window is blank]

Comment: can't you select it via the drop down in the properties window?

Comment: Hi Dirk,

No, can't see anything in the drop down either.

Comment: Even with the sheet being protected, there should be something in there... There still is the chance for your workbook to be corrupt :/ (does it work at other parts of your workbook? and if not, how about other workbook in general?)

Comment: It's the same situation in the rest of the sheets of the same workbook. However, everything's fine for activex controls of different workbooks.

Comment: That said, I assume that the workbook itself got an error... It is rare but happens sometimes and there is no easy solution for it. The only way I know, is creating a new workbook (then copy parts/sheets of the old to the new and save/close it every time). As soon as you got the same error like in the old workbook, you know where it may be... Still, depending of the size of the corrupt workbook, it can be a huge amount of work :(

Comment: Do the controls actually work?

Answer (score 5):

I just now had this problem and have solved it by viewing/unlocking my VBA project window.  I had previously done Excel VBA Project Window -> Tools -> VBA Project Properties -> Protection tab -> Checkmark at Lock project for viewing, and added a password.  To solve this, I did not remove that checkmark but only went to my VBA project window, expanded my project navigator pane and entered my password, and then right-click on the ActiveX control -> Properties, and can now see the ActiveX control's properties properly.  Is this the same for you?

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly old, but worth adding a response to.  In my case, my ActiveX button had VBA code behind it, and I password protected the VBA code editor.  Unlocking the VBA editor will allow the properties window on the form/sheet to populate.  I've noticed the same behavior in MS Access, surely by design.

(grammar edit)